# Python's 'python manage.py syncdb' draws a blank forever

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new to Django (but not to Python). I've installed Postgresql 9.3, PgAdmin3 and Psycopg2 successfully in Ubuntu Linux and tested Postgresql manually by creating a database called `mysite` and a few tables and it's working fine.

I've also tested Django from Python (`2.7.6`) and it displays the correct version of Django too (`1.6`).

I am using [Django's Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) for setting up everything. I was able to execute

`django-admin.py startproject mysite` and `python manage.py runserver` on localhost, port 8000 without any errors. However, whenever I run `python manage.py syncdb`, it draws a blank forever. It would be really appreciated if someone could help me out with this problem, been stuck for more than a week!

Here's my `settings.py`:

```
    """
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'mduc6%9mt+ca_ir_g6gq8nd(piu90cdtn^fn=u#2om8t=a8!en'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'NAME': 'mysite',
        'USER': 'akshat',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'PORT': 8000
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And here's the directory hierarchy when viewed from `~/Programming/Django/mysite`:

```
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
└── mysite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.py~
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── wsgi.py
    └── wsgi.pyc
```

Edit: Also, it doesn't show the error (mentioned in the comments) when the development server is ran, but it does with `python manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: Is your postgresql up? Check using `sudo service postgresql status`

Comment: @mu無 Yes, even my postgresql is online

Comment: Wait, its port is 5432, am I supposed to put the same in my settings.py?

Comment: If you use default port in postgres (5432) then you have to set this port in `settings.py`

Comment: So, I went ahead and did that, and now I'm getting this: http://pastie.org/private/crsi29tgpskzkw4qew5jhw

Comment: @AkshatTripathi based on the last line of your log, I think you put in your settings a wrong password to your database

Comment: also make sure you do have a database `mysite` which can be accessed by user `akshat` and your password

Comment: Double checked! Everything is perfect, the user `akshat` can get access to the database using the provided password, still, no luck.

Comment: Okay, I ran `psql` as the user `akshat` and it said that the role doesn't exist. I did `su postgres` and then `psql` to start using the database, which user should I specify in my `settings.py`? By the way, I've tried both and even 'root'-- they all have the same password!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current error of-

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "akshat"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "akshat"`

-you need to set up permissions for Postgres to use by editing the file */etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf*.

Just add the following line to the end of the file:

`local   database_name       user_name    md5`

Be sure to replace `database_name` with your database name as well as `user_name` with the actual user name.

Comment: Nope, same error. By the way, I'm using a virual environment, that shouldn't be a problem right? And I made the changes doing sudo for I was not able to view the file as user 'akshat'.